# boost::system::error_code producing error 158 unknown

Tags: c++, linux, boost, openwrt

I'm using `boost::system::error_code` to capture error codes to a log file and it's logging an `unknown error`. I haven't found any reference to this error in the Web.

```
bool read_response_payload(size_t payload_len)
{
     boost::system::error_code ec;
     stream_connector<protocol_type, INTERFACE_BUFFER_LEN,
            INTERFACE_TIMEOUT_SECS>::read_all(payload_len, ec);
     if (ec) {
            LOGGER_LOG_WARN("Interface read error: %s", ec.message().c_str());
            stream_connector<protocol_type, INTERFACE_BUFFER_LEN,
                INTERFACE_TIMEOUT_SECS>::disconnect();
            return false;
     }
     else {
            return true;
     }
}
```

In the log file I get messages like this:

```
Interface read error: Unknown error 158
```

The system is:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# uname -a
Linux OpenWrt 2.6.30.9 #4 Thu Jul 3 16:08:13 BRT 2014 rlx GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I guess it's an OpenWrt-specific error. Try to find it in OpenWrt docs or header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment it was an error described in `<asm/errno.h>` from OpenWRT

```
#define ECONNREFUSED    146 /* Connection refused */
#define EHOSTDOWN   147 /* Host is down */
#define EHOSTUNREACH    148 /* No route to host */
#define EWOULDBLOCK EAGAIN  /* Operation would block */
#define EALREADY    149 /* Operation already in progress */
#define EINPROGRESS 150 /* Operation now in progress */
#define ESTALE      151 /* Stale NFS file handle */
#define ECANCELED   158 /* AIO operation canceled */
```

It's an Asynchronous IO operation that has been cancelled.

Comment: It seems that openwrt uses errno numbering that differs from the "common" one. It would be nice to submit a patch for Asio...